# Why adding tabs to mat-tab-group doesn't work from separate component?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I try to do something like this in a component:

```
   <mat-tab-group>
     <mat-tab label="Zero">Contents for zero</mat-tab> 
     <app-tabs-container></app-tabs-container>
   </mat-tab-group>
```

tabs-container.component.html:

```
<mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let index = index" [label]="tab">
    Contents for {{tab}} tab
</mat-tab>
```

tabs-container.component.ts:

```
tabs = ['First', 'Second', 'Third'];
```

But it doesn't work. However it works  when I put it all in the component directly:

```
   <mat-tab-group
     <mat-tab label="Zero">Contents for zero</mat-tab> 
     <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let index = index" [label]="tab">
        Contents for {{tab}} tab
    </mat-tab>
   </mat-tab-group>
```

There is no error or anything. In TabsContainerComponent property tabs is initialized, constructor is called but tabs First-Third are not shown. What is the reason and is it possible to fix?

**EDIT**: Also if separate component has only 1 tab it's not shown.

tabs-container.component.html:

```
<mat-tab label="Single tab">
   Contents for single tab
</mat-tab>
```

Comment: @A.khalifa: typo

Comment: @A.khalifa: ? as I said there's no build errors or uncaught errors in console and the TabsCointainerComponent constructor is called.